# Image resizeMode='contain' not working in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

Here's the simplest code possible:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image resizeMode={'contain'} source={imageSource}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

If the resizeMode is set on 'center', it's working nearly as expected, but when in 'contain', the image does not resize. [The image is really huge](https://unsplash.com/photos/-jJQWjfVKec), but it does not resize... Where am I wrong? :)

Comment: Can you show the current result ? It should be the correct way of doing it. Also, you don't need the curly braces, you can simply write `resizeMode="contain"`

Comment: Did you set the style for image? Every image should have a height and width

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your image does not have the context of height and width. You need to specify it.

This should fix your issue:

```
 <Image
style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
resizeMode={"contain"}
source={imageSource}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that your image to be as width as your page you can use the code below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          resizeMode={'contain'}
          source={imageSource}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```